# Magento 1.9 Enable Sending Emails

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to enable emails sending in magento 1.9, so I enabled the contact us flag from the admin panel and I set all the addresses.

My Environment is:
Server: EC2 , Domain: Godaddy, Magento 1.9

I also added the MX records to godaddy.

But now magento not sending any email when I test contact us page.

Note: Also I setup the SMTP setting from admin->configuration->advance->mail

Any extra steps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the **SMTP configuration** and the **queued emails** !

Since **Magento 1.9.1**, the emails are not being sent **directly** during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob.

The **contact us** dont work, this one comes from the smtp issue if you hanevn't some error in your `contacts` module !.

I suggest you to install this free extension [SMTP Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html), set the SMTP config  connexion like Gmail for exemple, and **dont forget** to set `Queue Usage` to `never`, save and your problem is solved.